# Non-computable functions by summing computable functions

Tags: algorithms, computability

The problem is to show that you may get a non-computable (non-recursive) function if you sum up an infinite number of computable (recursive) functions.

$$g(x) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty f(x, i)$$

show that $g(x)$ is non recursive, where $f(X, i)$ is recursive.

Can I use

$$g(x) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty 2^f,$$

where $f(i)$ is the Busy Beaver function?

And why can't I just use something like this: let infinite number of $f(x, i)$ equal $1$, so the sum will be divergent, which means its not computable.

Comment: The way the problem is stated, you want the sum to be a non-computable function. If the sum diverges, it won't be a function.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be a non-recursive set. Let $f(x,i)$ be $1$ if $x=i\in A$ and $0$ in all other cases. So, for each fixed $i$, $f(X,i)$ is the characteristic function of the singleton $\{i\}$ if $i\in A$ and the identically zero function if $i\notin A$. In either case, it's recursive. But the sum over all $i$ is the characteristic function of $A$, which isn't recursive.

Comment: so i guess 1 means true and 0 means false right? here for this specific class we use opposite of that. so if i change f(x, i) to be 0 when x=i∈A and 1 when it doesnt then by the same logic ill prove for infinite multiplication right? Also if h(x, i) is not(sg(f(x, i)) then not(sg) of sum of h(x, i) over all i is my characteristic function then by the same logic that sum isnt recursive. Am i right? And shouldnt you put that sum into sg in your case as well?

Comment: @Hov (1) If you define the characteristic function of a set to be $0$ on the set and $1$ elsewhere, then just replace "characteristic function of" in my answer with "characteristic function of the complement of" and it's still OK. (2) The functions I"m using and their sum all have values only $0$ and $1$, so sg isn't needed.